# How to create Single Logic App for Multiple Http requests like for POST, GET, etc

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

**I am new to Azure logic Apps**

I want to create a logic App connector  **"when an HTTP request is a received"**  which should handle GET, POST, PUT, Delete as a single Logic APP.

Or

Is there a way that I will create logic App connector  "when an HTTP request is a received" for every request and I would be able to **share a single API to call those.**

Comment: how did you implement this solution?

Comment: Both ways mentioned below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two basic options.

1. Create 5 Logic Apps.  1 for each Verb, then one that does the actual work.  Each of the Verb Logic would call the work Logic App internally.
2. Use Azure API Management to create the 4 Verb endpoints which each redirect to a single Logic App, changing the Verb internally.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Will go through it.

Comment: I used the 2nd option (APIM). I did make an API and Added logic apps API URLs in that. when I call fetch it is working properly, but when I call to post it give me the following Error.    "error": {
        "code": "NoResponse",
        "message": "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. @johns-305

Comment: I used the 2nd option APIM and I was able to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create an azure function that will accept any of those verbs and have it route requests to the intended logic app.